# Use PIN or Password

Tags: authentication, passwords

Which one is better, using PIN or password ? I want my app using PIN number to user login and register. Does not matter if I use PIN number only for user login and registration in my web application ? Any opinion ?

Answer (score 2):

You should use a password, without any doubt.

A 4-digit PIN is easily crackable via brute-force; for this reason it is only used in conjunction with other mechanisms that deny access after a limited number of tries, e.g. SIM cards and bank cards.  Any other use is doomed to failure, as [the hacking of Google Wallet showed a few years ago](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2012/02/09/google_wallet_pin/).

Longer PINs are not easier to remember than a password and have significantly less entropy, hence are much less secure.